# move an object towards a target but in a sine wave

Tags: unity-game-engine, trigonometry

unity2d and by ship I mean spaceship. so I have my ship which I want to move to a specific target, but I want it to be in a sin wave so it bounces up and down, I've watched plenty of youtube tutorials but I still do not understand how to integrate it into my code.

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, shipTarget, Time.deltaTime * shipSpeed) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This script solves the problem. The `Mathf.Sin` function rotates a variable with angular motion in the period `0` to `2 * pi` between `-1` to `1`. Adding this method to the original location is the key. Just Add this to your object and select target in the inspector. you can move target and see result.

```cs
public class SinusMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float cycle; // This variable increases with time and allows the sine to produce numbers between -1 and 1.
    private Vector3 basePosition; // This variable maintains the location of the object without applying sine changes

    public Transform target;
    
    public float waveSpeed = 1f; // Higher make the wave faster
    public float bonusHeight = 1f; // Set higher if you want more wave intensity
    public float speed = 1f; // more value going faster to target
   
    public void Start() => basePosition = transform.position;

    void Update()
    {
        cycle += Time.deltaTime*waveSpeed;
    
        transform.position = basePosition + (Vector3.up*bonusHeight) * Mathf.Sin(cycle);
    
        if (target) basePosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(basePosition, target.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Remember that the script name and the file match, and also comment if there is a problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the spaceship is moving towards the direction `transform.position - shipTarget` and the oscillation in the direction perpendicular to the straight motion which takes the path of a `sine` wave, the `position` of the spaceship has to update in both the directions.

Let's have some variables for the **speed** of the spaceship that translates into a straight line, the **amplitude** and **frequency** of the `sine` wave, and finally the direction of the spaceship.

```
private float speed = 1f;
private float amplitude = 1f;
private float frequency = 1f;
private Vector2 straightDirection = (transform.position - shipTarget).normalized; // magnitude = 1
private Vector2 perpendicularDirection = GetPerpendicularDirection(straightDirection);
```

```
Vector2 GetPerpendicularDirection(Vector2 direction) {
    return new Vector2(-direction.y, direction.x);
}
```

---

**Player movement towards the target:**

```
Vector2 horizontal = straightDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

---

**Player movement in perpendicular direction**:

```
Vector2 vertical = perpendicularDirection * Mathf.Sin(frequency * Time.time) * amplitude;
```

Explaining it a bit, `Mathf.Sin(float)` takes in a floating-point value (which in this case is the total time elapsed since the **start** of the script, i.e. `Time.time`) in radians. Multiplying it with a **frequency** affects the `sine` wave's distance between two consecutive **crests** or **troughs**. More the **frequency**, less the distance between two consecutive **crests** and **troughs**. `Mathf.Sin(float)` reaches a maximum value of `1`. Likewise, `Mathf.Sin(float) * amplitude` reaches a maximum value of `amplitude`.

---

Summing up, **update** the `transform` of the spaceship every frame by calling it in the `Update()` function.

```
private void Update() {
    transform.position = horizontal + vertical;
}
```

Comment: wow what a detailed answer, thank you bro. unfortunately, i was not able to implement your given information into my script, got literally 58 error messages haha

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I've spent a good amount of time writing this, can you add your error messages here?